# Change powerpoint chart colors using vba

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

I'm trying to change all the charts in the current ppt from one themecolor to another. eg., if any Accent1 color is used in chart series or texts, then change those to Accent3.
I get a Type mismatch, runtime error 13 at oPoint (oPoint=Nothing). please help, how to fix this?

```
Sub ReplaceColors(OldColor As Variant, NewColor As Variant, oldTint As 
String, newTint As String, chkTexts As Boolean, chkShapes As Boolean, 
optTargetSlides As Boolean, chkGrouped As Boolean)

Dim i,t As Integer
Dim osld As Slide
Dim TargetSlides As SlideRange
Dim oshp As Shape
Dim oSeries As Series
Dim oPoint As Point
Dim x, y As Integer
Dim sBrightness as Variant
Dim oColor, nColor As ThemeColor
Dim oPP As Placeholders

Set TargetSlides = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range
For Each osld In TargetSlides
    For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
    With oshp
      If .Type = msoChart Then
              'Set oSeries = .Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
              For Each oSeries In .Chart.SeriesCollection
                For Each oPoint In oSeries.Points
                'oPoint.Format.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor
                    If oPoint.Format.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = OldColor And oPoint.Format.Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = oldTint Then
                    oPoint.Format.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = NewColor
                    oPoint.Format.Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = newTint
                    End If
                Next
               Next
      End If
   Next
Next
```

Comment: In your posted code, you haven't defined a variable or a value for OldColor, oldTint, NewColor or newTint. So it's hard to see how it could possible work. If the charts use a particular slide layout, an out-of-the-box solution would be to remap the color theme for that layout by hacking the XML. That way you can set Accent1 to map to Accent3. Here's my article with more detail: https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2018/12/xml-hacking-layout-color-variations-for-charts/

Comment: Hi @JohnKorchok I have updated the full function above for you. changing the layouts will not work for us, as we need to change the colors of charts in the same template layout. I just need the code to change the chart colors from one theme color to another.

Comment: Try substituting _.SchemeColor_ for .ObjectThemeColor. Is there some reason why the Sub has all these unused arguments? _chkTexts As Boolean, chkShapes As Boolean, optTargetSlides As Boolean, chkGrouped As Boolean_

Comment: Hi @JohnKorchok this is a big function which has other code blocks that use those variables, I trimmed to the error part only. The 'Type Mismatch' error occurs in the line "For Each oSeries In .Chart.SeriesCollection", even before the .ObjectThemeColor , which works fine on other places in this sub, just not for charts.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, we expect minimal reproducible examples. We're not going to re-create your macro to test it. Here's a how-to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I doubt it's causing your error, but your list has _With oshp_ without a corresponding _End With_ statement.